# Can't install BigARTM python library on linux

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to install BigARTM on my mint following [this](http://docs.bigartm.org/en/latest/installation/linux.html) instruction, all steps seems to be passed successful, for example last one:

```
*@*​-PC ~ $ cd ~/bigartm/python
​*@*​-PC ~/bigartm/python $ sudo python setup.py install
```

returns: `...Finished processing dependencies for bigartm==0.8.0`

So `import artm` gives me import error ([this](https://github.com/bigartm/bigartm/wiki/BigARTM-Cookbook-for-Python) is how it might be imported)
What might be wrong?

Comment: This is not an error. What made you think it did't installed succesfully?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs trying to import the library from the console and from ipython notebook